# MongoDB embedded documents: size limit and aggregation performance concerns

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In MongoDB's documentation it is suggested to put as much data as possible in a single document. It is also suggested NOT to use **ObjectId ref** based sub-documents unless the data of those sub-documents must be referenced from more than one document.

In my case I have a **one-to-many** relationship like this:

**Log** schema:

```
const model = (mongoose) => {
    const LogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        result: { type: String, required: true },
        operation: { type: Date, required: true },
        x: { type: Number, required: true },
        y: { type: Number, required: true },
        z: { type: Number, required: true }
    });
    const model = mongoose.model("Log", LogSchema);
    return model;
};
```

**Machine** schema:

```
const model = (mongoose) => {
    const MachineSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        model: { type: String, required: true },
        description: { type: String, required: true },
        logs: [ mongoose.model("Log").schema ]
    });
    const model = mongoose.model("Machine", MachineSchema);
    return model;
};
module.exports = model;
```

Each **Machine** will have many **Production_Log** documents (more than one million). Using embedded documents I hitted the 16mb per document limit very quickly during my tests and I couldn't add any more **Production_Log** documents to the **Machine** documents.

**My doubts**

1. Is this a case where one should be using sub-documents as **ObjectId** references instead of embedded documents?
2. Is there any other solution I could evaluate?
3. I will be accessing **Production_Log** documents to generate stats for each **Machine** using the  aggregation framework. Should I have any extra consideration on the schema design?

Thank you very much in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is not applicable to MongoDB

MongoDB scales better if you store full information in the single document (Data redundancy). Database normalization obligate split data in different collections, but once growth your data, it will cause bottlenecks issues.

Use only `LOG` Schema:

```
const model = (mongoose) => {
    const LogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        model: { type: String, required: true },
        description: { type: String, required: true },
        result: { type: String, required: true },
        operation: { type: Date, required: true },
        x: { type: Number, required: true },
        y: { type: Number, required: true },
        z: { type: Number, required: true }
    });
    const model = mongoose.model("Log", LogSchema);
    return model;
};
```

Read / Write operation scales fine in this way.

With [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) you can process data and compute desired result.

Answer (score -1):

Please see if this approach suits your need

The `Log` collection would be having more data generated whereas the `Machine` collection never exceed 16MB. Instead of embedding `Log` collection into `Machine` collection try the vice versa.

Your modified schema would be like this

**Machine schema:**

```
const model = (mongoose) => {
    const MachineSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        model: { type: String, required: true },
        description: { type: String, required: true }        
    });
    const model = mongoose.model("Machine", MachineSchema);
    return model;
};
module.exports = model;
```

**Log schema:**

```
const model = (mongoose) => {
    const LogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        result: { type: String, required: true },
        operation: { type: Date, required: true },
        x: { type: Number, required: true },
        y: { type: Number, required: true },
        z: { type: Number, required: true },
        machine: [ mongoose.model("Machine").schema ]
    });
    const model = mongoose.model("Log", LogSchema);
    return model;
};
```

If still we are overshooting the size of Document(16MB) then in the Log Schema we can create a new document for every Day/Hour/Week depending on the logs we are generating.

Comment: Hi Clement, thanks for your reply. Wouldn't be better to have an array of LogSchema references in the MachineSchema instead?

The relationship is one MACHINE to many LOG.

Or maybe to have a single MachineSchema reference in the LogSchema...

Comment: The Better approach would be having a schema which is not having relationship. The designs which we are discussing are not best fit to use a NoSQL DB, these relationships are based out of the RDBMS world, where the normalizations and no duplicates takes a prime objective in RDBMS DB. NoSQL DB is designed to handle huge data, whereas it is allowed to duplicate the data and design the schema supporting our output. Here we can try on keeping a copy of machine details in each log entry(created per day/week/month - whichever doesn't exceeds our size) is better performing while retrieving records

Comment: NoSQL DB's are designed to handle huge data and in such cases if we go for more relations as we do have in RDBMS our retrieval of records would be really hit by performance and which will not give us a good user experience. Best option would be going with single schema as given in the solution provided by Valijon